# Java 2D array assigning different values at different intervals

Tags: java, arrays

I apologize if I'm not clear. I'm new to programming. So lets say I have a `char[10][10]`. And there are two+ chars I want to assign at intervals for example `i[0][0]` to `i[5][7]` have `Y` and the rest have `N`. How would  I do that if its possible? I've been trying to figure it out for 6+ hours.

Comment: Nested for loops with a couple of if blocks and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to have a 'for' block that goes through the rows and another 'for' block that goes through the columns. it could be something like

```
char[] arr= {'Y','N'};
int counter = 0; // <- these are optional depending on what you choose below
for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
    for(int k=0;k<10;k++){
        // i[j][k]= here you should assign the value
        counter++;
    }
}
```

The way to assign the value depends on what you want to do. If you want to have it to generate randomly you can do something like `i[j][k]= arr[(int)(Math.random()*2)]` or if you want to have it alternate between Y and N you could have a counter variable and assign `i[j][k]= arr[counter%2]` . If you want to assign the first half to 'Y' and the other half to 'N'  `i[j][k]= (counter<=50)?'Y':'N';`. And the particular case you ask would be `i[j][k]= (j<=5 && k<=7)?'Y':'N';`It really depends much on what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with loops.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
      i[i][j] = 'N';
   }
   for(int j = 7; j < 10; j++){
      i[i][j] = 'Y';
   }
}
for(int i = 5; i < 10; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      i[i][j] = 'Y';
   }
}
```

Comment: While the answer is an actual answer. It may be a good idea to give a little bit of an explanation. The question does state `I apologize if I'm not clear. I'm new to programming`

Comment: Thats a good point -- I guess if it were me I would prefer to just see a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[][] theArray = new char[10][10]
upToX = 5; // limit for rows
upToY = 7; // limit for columns

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
   for(int j = 0; j< 10; j++ ){
      if((i+1)*(j+1) <= (upToX+1)*(upToY+1)){ 
         theArray[i][j] = 'Y';
      }
      else{
         theArray[i][j] = 'N';
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using for-loops and if-else. Since you are looking for yes/no type values, I just used `boolean` type in my example

```
boolean[][] arr = new boolean[10][10];
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if(i < 6 && j < 8) 
            arr[i][j] = true;
        else
            arr[i][j] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It sets arr[5][8]= false. arr[5][9]=false.

Comment: How should this `for(int i : arr)` work? That array contains `boolean` and not `int`.